# Java BufferedWriter close()

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedwriter

Assume that I have the following code fragment:

```
operation1();
bw.close();
operation2();
```

When I call `BufferedReader.close()` from my code, I am assuming my JVM makes a system call that ensures that the buffer has been flushed and written to disk. I want to know if `close()` waits for the system call to complete its operation or does it proceed to `operation2()` without waiting for `close()` to finish.

To rephrase my question, when I do `operation2()`, can I assume that `bw.close()` has completed successfully?

Comment: You meant BufferedWriter, I guess

Comment: define "completed succesfully"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *when I do operation2(), can I assume that bw.close()  has completed successfully?*

Yes

Answer (score 4):

> Close the stream, flushing it first. Once a stream has been closed, further write() or flush() invocations will cause an IOException to be thrown. Closing a previously-closed stream, however, has no effect.

Though the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#close()) does not say anything specifically, I would assume this call does block until finished. In fact, I'm pretty sure nothing in the `java.io` package is non-blocking.

Answer (score 4):

The JavaDoc for the `java.io.BufferedReader.close()` is taken exactly from the contract if fulfills with the `java.io.Reader`.

The Doc says:

> Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it. Once the stream has been closed, further read(), ready(), mark(), reset(), or skip() invocations will throw an IOException. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.

While this makes no explicit claim of blocking until the file system is complete, with this same instance of `BufferedReader` all other operations will throw an exception if `close()` returns. Although the JavaDoc could be seen as ambiguous about when the operation completes, if the file system flush and close were not complete when this method returned it would violate the spirit of the contract and be a bug in Java (implementation or documentation).

Answer (score 2):

NO! You cannot be sure for the following reason:

A BufferedWriter is a Wrapper for another Writer. A close() to the BufferedWriter just propagates to the underlying Writer.

IF this underlying Writer is an OutputStreamWriter, and IF the OutputStream is a FileOutputStream, THEN the close will issue a system call to close the file handle.

You are completely free to even have a Writer where close() is a noop, or where the close is implemented non-blocking, but when using only classes from java.io, this is never the case.

Answer (score 1):

A `Writer` (or `BufferedWriter`) is a black box that writes a stream of characters somewhere, not necessarily to the disk. A call to [`close()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#close()) *must* (by method contract) flush its buffered content before closing, and *should* (normally) block before all its "essential" work is done. But this would depend on the implementation and the environment (you cannot know about caches that are below the Java layer, for example). In what respects of the work to be done by the Java writer itself (eg: make the system call to write to disk, in the case of a FileWriter or akin, and close the filehandle) , yes, you can assume that when `close()` returns it has already done all its work.

Answer (score 1):

In general with any i/o operation you can make no assumptions about what has happened after the `write()` operation completes, even after you `close`. The idea of `delivery` is a subjective concept relative to the medium.

For instance, what if the `writer` represents a TCP connection, and then the data is lost inbetween client and server? Or what if the kernel writes data to a disk, but the drive physically fails to write it? Or if the writer represents a carrier pigeon that gets shot en route?

Furthermore, imagine the case when the write has no way of confirming that the endpoint has received the data (read: udp/datagrams). What should the blocking policy be in that situation?

Answer (score 1):

The buffer will have been flushed to the operating system and the file handle closed, so the Java operations required will have been completed.

BUT the operating system will have cached or queued the write to the actual disk, pipe, network, whatever - there is no guarantee that the physical write has completed. FileChannel.force() provides a way to do that for files on local disks: see the Javadoc.

Comment: particularly windows falls victim to this--if you close a file then turn around and re-open and read it, you might not get all the bytes back if you are too fast...

Comment: @rogerdpack I've been around Windows systems since 1988 and I have never seen this.

Comment: Appears I was wrong--the situation I was thinking of was http://epirsch.blogspot.com/2008/01/fixing-attachmentfu-on-windows-like.html where performing an fflush wasn't enough to make File#stat see the bytes (required an fsync also).  Other problems I've seen are on a network share, if you close a file, then read it from a separate computer, it may be incomplete.  At least in Linux with GPFS.  And also in windows after you delete a file programmatically, sometimes it's "still there" for a split second if you enumerate files. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ***IF*** you reach `operation2();`, the stream would've had to have been completely closed. However, `close() throws IOException`, so you may not even get to `operation2();`. This may or may not be the behavior that you expect.

Comment: in which case he wouldn't *"do operation2()"* in first place.

Comment: @Oscar: the original words are "WHEN I do `operation2()`". English is not my first language, but I think WHEN is stronger than IF, and it may or may not matter in this context.

Comment: *..English is not my first language..* mine neither and now,  I'm totally confused  :)

Comment: @Oscar: what I understand is that in English, saying "if" something happens have a different implication than saying "when" something happens. "when" is stronger because the implication is that it will happen, it's only a question of timing. "if" has no guarantee that it will happen in the first place. That's precisely what I'm trying to emphasis here: `operation2();` is not a simple matter of "when". It's an "if".